Idiot's guide to testing switches
Can someone guide me on how to test the switches in my home? Because everything I'm seeing online is causing my switches to pop when testing with a multimeter.
I have single pole and three way switches. I need to know how to:

test that the circuit is on
test that the circuit is off
test that it's wired correctly

I have a multimeter, and I thought I knew how to use it, but now I'm not so sure.

Please define ‘pop’. Are you creating a spark, tripping the circuit breaker, or something else?

And can you also clarify why you want to test? ‘Wired correctly’ usually means the light goes on/off when you flip the switch, without tripping the circuit breaker. On and off are usually indicated by current going to the light fixture.

It sounds like you have confused switches with circuit breakers. If the former "pop,"  they are dangerously defective. If the latter pop, something in your house's wiring or your appliances is probably dangerously defective, and it is probably not the circuit breaker.

Testing switches isn't a common part of house wiring diagnosis. (You'd test the wiring, not the switch.) What are you trying to accomplish, exactly?

you are probably using the multimeter incorrectly ... please stop what you are doing before you collect the Darwin award


Turn off the breaker for the circuit. If there are multiple switches in a single box then make sure all breakers for all switches in the box are off for safety.
Use a non-contact voltage tester to test at all screws/connection points around all switches in the box.


If there is still voltage present, find the correct breaker and try again. Note that in some miswired configurations you may have more than one breaker involved in a single switch/circuit. Multiple switches can legitimately be on different circuits (if wired correctly) or on the same circuit.

For a single switch, check for continuity between the two main screws/terminals with switch "on" and "off". You should have continuity when "on" and not when "off".

For a three-way switch, check for continuity between each pair of screws. You should have two screws of one color and one screw of another color. (The typical colors are black, brass, silver.) The two screws of the same color should never have continuity. Each of those two screws should show continuity with the different color screw when the switch is in one position and no continuity in the other position.



I will add that most multi-meters can test continuity by sending low voltage battery power to one of the test leads when used on the ohms setting. Output voltage can usually be adjusted (with a knob or wheel on the side of the meter if analog). Touching the test leads together will show the voltage output on the meter display. See your tester's user manual.
